# Can I modify defaults to get a website to popup when I hold down a letter on the keyboard?

Tags: ios, ipad, mac, keyboard, hacking

You know how if you hold down 'i' on the keyboard you get î, ï, í, ī, į, and ì by selecting from number 1-6, well, what if I want, say, for example, igloo.com to pop up as a seventh option when I hold down i. That way I can store things in my keys, even longer stuff not necessarily websites.

Comment: You can't modify the keyboard Press-And-Hold for iOS, but I am wondering why Keyboard Shortcuts don't work for you?

Comment: Press and hold can't be a "key combination?"

Comment: press-and-hold can't be modified in iOS.  It's even protected now via SIP in macOS, so it technically can't be anything except what Apple defines it as.  The question still remains...does Keyboard Shortcuts not work?

Comment: No, it does, but I just thought it'd be a cool feature, no?

Comment: I can see the value in it.